# Add "Xamarin.Android" to self-hosted agent

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, azure-pipelines

I tried to build a Xamarin App with Azure pipelines with a self-hosted agent, and I came across this error

> [error]No agent found in pool MyPool which satisfies the following
> demand: Xamarin.Android.All demands: MSBuild, Xamarin.Android, Agent.Version -gtVersion 2.163.1

According to this [link](https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-pipelines-agent/issues/1043), The reason seems to be that I don't have "Xamarin.Android" in my agent as I found it absent from the "Capabilities".

I am using personal pc windows 11, with PowerShell, runing ".\run.cmd" for the agent.

Can someone advise how to add this capability to my self-hosted agent?

---

[Edited] The "Agent version" shown on the pool from Azure DevOps is 2.217.2. According to this [link](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/jdk-capability-is-not-automatically-detected-on-on/1037817), the version is good enough.

Answer (score 1):

I found I only need to add a "User-defined capabilities" Xamarin.Android and make the value same as the ANDROID_HOME, in my case is C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk